# Java RabbitMQ + AMQP blocking producers for some period(Locking)

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

**Issue:** We have 2 or 3 instances of an application. Each instance has a producer and a consumer. We have to schedule some process and for this we use common spring scheduler. This scheduler produces messages and throws them to a "Broker" (RabbitMQ). In our case we process the same data 2 or 3 times because each instance throws the message. How would you block the producer of instances until first producer will throw a message?

Configuration:

```
<!-- RabbitMQ configuration -->
<rabbit:connection-factory
        id="connection" host="${rabbit.host}" port="${rabbit.port}"      username="${rabbit.username}" password="${rabbit.password}"
        channel-cache-size="${rabbit.publisherCacheSize}" virtual-host="${rabbit.virtualHost}" />

<!-- Declare executor pool for worker threads -->
<!-- Ensure that the pool-size is greater than the sum of all number of concurrent consumers from rabbit that use this pool to ensure
     you have enough threads for maximum concurrency. We do this by ensuring that this is 1 plus the size of the connection factory cache
     size for all consumers -->
<task:executor id="worker-pool" keep-alive="60" pool-size="${rabbit.consumerChannelCacheSize}" queue-capacity="1000" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


<!-- Message converter -->
<bean id="baseMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound" value="com.company.model.Scraper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="baseMessageConverter"/>
</bean>


<!-- *********************************producer*********************************** -->
<!-- Outbound company Events -->
<int:channel id="producerChannelCompany"/>
<int:gateway id="jobcompanyCompleteEventGateway" service-interface="com.company.eventing.companyEventPublisher"
             default-request-channel="producerChannelCompany"
             default-request-timeout="2000"
             error-channel="errors"/>

<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="companyEvents.amqpAdapter" channel="producerChannelCompany"
                               exchange-name="${rabbit.queue.topic}"
                               routing-key="${rabbit.queue.routing.key}"
                               amqp-template="psRabbitTemplate"/>

<rabbit:admin id="psRabbitAdmin" connection-factory="connection" />
<rabbit:template id="psRabbitTemplate" channel-transacted="${rabbit.channelTransacted}" encoding="UTF-8" message-converter="messageConverter" connection-factory="connection"/>
<rabbit:topic-exchange id="ps.topic" name="${rabbit.queue.topic}" durable="true" auto-delete="false"/>



<!-- *********************************consumer*********************************** -->
<rabbit:queue id="ps.queue" name="${rabbit.queue}"  auto-delete="false" durable="true" exclusive="false"  />


<!-- Exchange to queue binding -->
<rabbit:topic-exchange id="ps.topic" name="${rabbit.queue.topic}" durable="true" auto-delete="false" >
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="${rabbit.queue}" pattern="${rabbit.queue.pattern}"></rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>

<!-- Configuration for consuming company Complete events -->
<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="companyAdapter"
                              channel="companyCompleteEventChannel"
                              queue-names="${rabbit.queue}"
                              channel-transacted="${rabbit.channelTransacted}"
                              prefetch-count="${rabbit.prefetchCount}"
                              concurrent-consumers="${rabbit.concurrentConsumers}"
                              connection-factory="connection"
                              message-converter="messageConverter"
                              task-executor="worker-pool"
                              error-channel="errors"/>



<int:channel id="companyCompleteEventChannel"/>
<int:service-activator id="companyCompleteActivator" input-channel="companyCompleteEventChannel"
                       ref="companyEventHandler" method="runScraper"/>

<bean id="jvmLauncher" class="com.app.company.jvm.JvmLauncher" />
<!-- company Event handler -->
<bean id="companyEventHandler" class="com.app.company.eventing.consumer.companyEventHandler" depends-on="jvmLauncher">
    <!--<property name="scriptHelper" ref="scriptHelper"/>-->
    <property name="jvmLauncher" ref="jvmLauncher" />
    <property name="defaultMemoryOptions" value="${company.memory.opts}"/>
    <property name="defaultMemoryRegex" value="${company.memory.regex}"/>
</bean>


<!-- ERRORS -->
<int:channel id="errors"/>
<int:service-activator id="psErrorLogger" input-channel="errors" ref="psloggingHandler"/>

<bean id="psloggingHandler" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="DEBUG"></constructor-arg>
    <!-- <property name="loggerName" value="com.app.travelerpayments.loggingHandler"/> -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Main idea of question is describe loosing message from Rabbit server, e.g. that means the RabbitMQ admins show me that message was delivered successful but "event" didn`t happen. May be connection sometime losted because both systems are located on different server

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what architecture you have, but if all your instances consume messages from the same queue, each message will be consumed only once (unless requeued by consumer). It the best way to use AMQP power in you situation, I guess. And if I missed something, please clarify your question.

With a-la fanout messages delivery, when each instance has their own queue with own messages stack and you want to controls messages delivery by your own (definitely, it's bad idea in almost all situations), why not let all instances to listen to personal queue(s)  bounded to fanout exchange and use this exchange for control messages. You can tell instances when to stop or start consuming, flush their queues, schedule restart, etc.

Note, you can use also topic exchange and bind queues by specific routing key, say "control.*"

The idea is to send `who is free` request, pick the random free worker and send payload to it. You can use specific routing key or just publish payload to default exchange with routing key same as queue name (by default queues bounded to default exchange with routing key same as queue name, see section [Default Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-default) in RabbitMQ docs).

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Previous configuration was provided for processing as you described above.